# Building comprehensive scraping program/database for real estate websites

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, automation, scrapy

I have a project I’m exploring where I want to scrape the real estate broker websites in my country (30-40 websites of listings) and keep the information about each property in a database.

I have experimented a bit with scraping in python using both BeautifulSoup and Scrapy.

What I would Ideally like to achieve is a daily updated database that will find new properties and remove properties when they are sold.

Any pointers as to how to achieve this? 
I am relatively new to programming and open to learning different languages and resources if python isn’t suitable.

Sorry if this forum isn’t intended for this kind of vague question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Build a scraper and schedule a daily run. You can use scrapy and the daily run will update the database daily.